# Gnome (Debian 11): How to install en_DK formats (date, numbers, units)?

Tags: gnome, locale, i18n, units

I switched my system from Debian 10 to 11 (new computer), so I'm trying to revert to my normal settings. I have installed with en_US locale, which I do want for UI texts, but I need to revert to ISO formats, like "normal" dates with 4-digit years, 24 hours, millimetres, centimetres, A4 page format etc. I open the Gnome "Region & Language" settings, but I can't seem to be able to install a new format. IIRC, I had used `en_DK` before, which is basically a neutral English but good date, time, and unit formats. How do I add `en_DK` in my new system for Gnome - only the formats part of Region & Language?
[image: screen from Region & Language; not possible to select Denmark]

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I had already noted down the process some years ago, it still works:

`$ sudo vim /etc/locale.gen`

Find and enable the line `en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8`, save and exit.

`$ sudo locale-gen`

Now open Gnome 'Region & Language' settings again.